# Calculating Inter-purchase Time in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,3,3,3)
date<-c("23-01-07","27-01-07","30-01-07","11-12-07","12-12-07","01-01-08")
df<-data.frame(id,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")


id    date      date2
1 23-01-07 2007-01-23
1 27-01-07 2007-01-27
1 30-01-07 2007-01-30
3 11-12-07 2007-12-11
3 12-12-07 2007-12-12
3 01-01-08 2008-01-01
```

Now I need to calculate the inter-purchase time of transactions for each id (the number of days between each transaction of a customer and the previous transaction by the same customer); so that I get the following result:

```
id    date      date2  interpurchase.time
1 23-01-07 2007-01-23         0
1 27-01-07 2007-01-27         4 
1 30-01-07 2007-01-30         3
3 11-12-07 2007-12-11         0  
3 12-12-07 2007-12-12         1 
3 01-01-08 2008-01-01        20
```

I wonder if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: And how do you define that exactly?

Comment: @flodel you have to guess it :)

Comment: @flodel it is the number of days between every two consecutive records of a customer (id).

Comment: Man, that was embarrassing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "id", transform, inter.time = c(0, diff(date2)))
```

or `ave`:

```
transform(df, inter.time = ave(as.numeric(date2), id,
                               FUN = function(x)c(0, diff(x))))
```

Both give

```
#   id     date      date2 inter.time
# 1  1 23-01-07 2007-01-23          0
# 2  1 27-01-07 2007-01-27          4
# 3  1 30-01-07 2007-01-30          3
# 4  3 11-12-07 2007-12-11          0
# 5  3 12-12-07 2007-12-12          1
# 6  3 01-01-08 2008-01-01         20
```

P.S.: you might want to replace these zeroes with `NA`.