# Obtaining average inter-purchase time with all dates in one column in R

Tags: r, time, crm

I am currently developing a timeframe for a churn dataset in R. In order
to do so I need the average inter-purchase time of each customer.

The example data below shows two customers (customer 1 and 2) buying on 3 and 2 separate occasions respectively. The average time between purchases for customer 1 is 7.5 days ((9+6)/2), and the average time between purchases for customer 2 is simply 5 days, as there are only two observations for this customer. In code it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(cust_id=c(1,2,1,2,1), 
    order_date=as.Date(c("2012-8-14", "2012-7-1", "2012-8-23", "2012-7-6" 
    "2012-8-29")))
```

and graphically it looks something like this:

```
    cust_id    order_date
1   1          2012-8-14 
2   2          2012-7-1
3   1          2012-8-23
4   2          2012-7-6
5   1          2012-8-29
```

Eventually I want it to look like this:

```
    cust_id    avg_interpurchase_time
1   1          7.5 
2   2          5
```

Is anyone able to point in me the right direction?

Thanks!

P.S. I have looked at  the following post: [Calculating Inter-purchase Time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773535/calculating-inter-purchase-time-in-r) but I believe my question differs from the question posed there. I have all dates in one column and one customer can have up to 80 dates, whereas the guy who posted that has only two dates for each customer spread out over 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you could use `aggregate` together with a custom function:

```
aggregate(order_date ~ cust_id, data=df, FUN=function(x) mean(diff(x)))
  cust_id order_date
1       1       7.5 
2       2       5.0
```

Here, we take the difference by order date and then calculate the mean. Note that this requires that the data are sorted by date. You could make sure this is true by including `order` in the call to the data.frame, as in `data=df[order(df$order_date),]` for example.

**data**
Includes a couple of typo corrections from OP.

```
df <- 
structure(list(cust_id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), order_date = structure(c(15566, 
15522, 15575, 15527, 15581), class = "Date")), .Names = c("cust_id", 
"order_date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Apologies for the typos and thanks for fixing them!

Answer (score 2):

Mayeb use dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% summarise(avg_internetpurchase_time = mean(diff(order_date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `dplyr` solution. Note that you made a typo in the year of the second purchase of cust_id 2. Therefore it averages to 371 instead of 5.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% arrange(order_date) %>% mutate(dif = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>% 
  summarise(avg_purchase = mean(dif, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Thanks for spotting the typo too, I will edit it out. I'm afraid my example is not representative enough of the entire data set. For example, with the code you supplied, I get an average inter-purchase time of -48.5 for a customer with the following dates: 2015-09-03, 2014-09-08, 2015-05-29 (in that exact order when the data is grouped by cust_id). This should however be 180 (263+97)/2.  Any idea why this might appear to be so?

Comment: I assumed your dataset was already ordered as in the example. I added the sorting, what makes my answer identical to that of epi99.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but includes sorting (arrange)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(cust_id)  %>%
  arrange(order_date) %>%
  mutate(t = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>%
  summarize(avg_interpurchase_time = mean(t, na.rm=T))
```