# Calculating Interpurchase time with the first transaction subtracted from a reference date

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2)
date <- c("2011-01-18","2011-01-31","2011-01-02","2011-01-15")
df <- data.frame(id,date)

id  date
1 2011-01-18
1 2011-01-31
2 2011-01-02
2 2011-01-15
```

Now, i would like to calculate the inter-purchase time of the first transaction with a reference date (2011-01-01) and the second transaction is the difference between second and first. So i get the following result

```
id  date     interpurchase_time
1 2011-01-18  17
1 2011-01-31  13
2 2011-01-02  01
2 2011-01-15  13
```

Could anyone please help me out with this? I am just a beginner is R

Thanks

P.S- I have looked upto this [Calculating Inter-purchase time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773535/calculating-inter-purchase-time-in-r) but here the first transaction is considered as zero which i do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag` function to compare each `date` with the previous one, for each `id`, but when there's no previous date you can use a default one (2011-01-01 in your case).

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2)
date <- c("2011-01-18","2011-01-31","2011-01-02","2011-01-15")
df <- data.frame(id,date)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         int_time = as.numeric(date - lag(date, default = ymd("2011-01-01")))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      id date       int_time
#   <dbl> <date>        <dbl>
# 1     1 2011-01-18       17
# 2     1 2011-01-31       13
# 3     2 2011-01-02        1
# 4     2 2011-01-15       13
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, note the answer in the related question you linked to can be modified to solve your problem as follows:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "id", transform, inter.time = diff(c(as.Date('2011-01-01'), date)))


  id       date inter.time
1  1 2011-01-18    17 days
2  1 2011-01-31    13 days
3  2 2011-01-02     1 days
4  2 2011-01-15    13 days
```

That is, if you first convert your dates using `as.Date()` when you create your dataframe:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2)
date <- as.Date(c("2011-01-18","2011-01-31","2011-01-02","2011-01-15"))
df <- data.frame(id,date)
```